# How to make dynamically created object's event handler reference a DGV object in another class?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I've created a class `dgvRoll` which I am using to write dynamic methods for DataGridView controls that are assigned to Form1 at runtime. I also added a slider control to the DGV which I fitted onto a cell. Find visual reference here:

[DGV Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik44W.jpg)

Here's the problem, I need the slider control's event handler (or any generic control added to the DGV at runtime) to communicate with the datagridview. A shorthand example of this is below:

```
class dgvRoll
{
    public void Loader(DataGridView dataGridView1)
    {
        // REMOVED IRRELEVANT CODE FROM LOADER METHOD
        Dynamic_CTRLs(dataGridView1);
    }

    public void Dynamic_CTRLs(DataGridView dataGridView1)
    {
        Counter = 0; // SET TO ZERO FOR SIMPLICITY
        var sldrCtrl = new RangeSlider();
        sldrCtrl.Name = "sldr" + Counter;

        // ADD CONTROL
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(sldrCtrl);

        // ADD EVENT HANDLER
        sldrCtrl.Click += new EventHandler(sldrCrtl_Click);
    }

    /*
```

HERE IS THE MAJOR ISSUE: I NEED DATAGRIDVIEW1 TO REFERENCE THE DGV IN FORM1
AS OPPOSED TO CREATING A NEW DGV. I TRIED TO PASS A DGV OBJECT AS AN ADDITIONAL PARAMETER
IN THE CLICK EVENT BUT THE HANDLER WILL NOT RECOGNIZE IT.
*/

```
    public virtual void sldrCrtl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RangeSlider sldrCtrl = (RangeSlider)sender;

        // CREATING NEW DGV HERE VERSUS REFERENCING EXISTING DGV IN FORM 1 IS THE PROBLEM
        // POSSIBLE TO ADD ANOTHER OBJECT AS PARAMETER IN CLICK EVENT HANDLER?? 
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        int Diff;
        int sldrCol = 1;
        var rowNum = default(int);
        string name = "sldr";

        try
        {
            Diff = sldrCtrl.Name.Length - name.Trim().Length;
            // ROWNUM IN THIS EXAMPLE EQUALS ZERO
            rowNum = Convert.ToInt32(sldrCtrl.Name.Substring(sldrCtrl.Name.Length - Diff, Diff));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        // THROWS NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION HERE
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum].Cells[sldrCol];
    }
}
```

Below is the code to assign the dgv class to dataGridView1 in Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // DGV OBJECT
    DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ASSIGN DGV LOAD METHOD
        dataGridView1.Parent = this.tabCtrl.TabPages[0];
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        dgvRoll dgv = new dgvRoll();
        dgv.Loader(this.dataGridView1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking a look and any helpful suggestions!

Comment: Correct, `DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();` won't work since it's "new" and not the control on the screen.  You can try modifying your RangeSlider class to hold a reference to a grid control, and pass the grid control through the constructor, where you would have `var sldrCtrl = new RangeSlider(dataGridView1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, if you wanted to, assign the DataGridView to the Tag property of the RangeSlider in the Dynamic_CTRLs method, like so:

```
var sldrCtrl = new RangeSlider();
sldrCtrl.Name = "sldr" + Counter;
sldrCtrl.Tag = dataGridView1;//   <-------look here
```

Then in sldrCrtl_Click do this:

```
RangeSlider sldrCtrl = (RangeSlider)sender;
DataGridView dataGridView1 = (DataGridView)sldrCtrl.Tag;
```

And you can do that for any control, so long as it is derived from the Control class.

Comment: this works. Thanks! Is this the only way you are aware of? Also, can the tag property reference multiple objects?

Comment: There are certainly other ways, but to do exactly what you want (pass the dgv into the event handler) I think this is the most straightforward. The tag property can only reference a single "object", but that object could be a list (like List<object>) or collection or a class that contains multiple references to other objects, etc... So long as you know in the event handler what to expect.

Comment: By the way, you should probably put a check around the line (datagridview = (datagridview)sldrCtrl.Tag) to make sure you indeed have a datagridview. If it is null or some other type of object you will have a runtime error, as you probably know.

Comment: Another way to do this would be to create wrapper classes for your controls, then create custom EventArgs classes that add the things you want/need... It would take more text then is allowed in these comments to explain, but if you want to do the research it is not all that hard. Maybe overkill though.